# Debian: Failed to stop unattended-upgrades.service

Tags: debian, bugs, unattended-upgrades

Running a Debian 9 (stretch). During every installation/removal of a package I get the following error thrown

> Failed to start unattended-upgrades.service: Unit unattended-> upgrades.service failed to load: Invalid argument

```
systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service

● unattended-upgrades.service - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:unattended-upgrade(8)
```

I neither can remove `unattended-upgrades` (v0.93.1) nor find anything helpful on the web (in other related `unattended-upgrades` questions) to solve this issue.

Workaround: I manually deleted `/lib/systemd/unattended.upgrades.service`. After that, I could do `sudo apt-get remove unattended-upgrades`. I would prefer to reinstall it with a working setup though.

Comment: To start with,  what errors (if any) do the logs `/var/log/unattended-upgrades`, contain, if anything? Post anything that looks like it might be relevant.

Comment: @FaheemMitha please see https://gist.github.com/pat-s/81847150c9ed3e97134138f47df94ce0 for /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

Comment: That particular log doesn't seem to show anything out of the ordinary. Look for some errors (if you can find them) and post those.

Comment: `apt-get remove unattended-upgrades` fails for me because, surprise, `Failed to start unattended-upgrades.service: .. ` ... just like the original. I don't have it in /lib/systemd however it was in /etc/init.d so I just moved it from there before attempting the remove (which then worked).